# Detect new posts in the channel and forward it to other channel - telegram bot using setwebhook - php code

Tags: php, telegram-bot

i want detect post id of new post in telegram channel with telegram bot that is admin in channel and forward new post to other channel that I have already specified

i tried to get id of post that bot forwarded to channel with this php code below

```
function bot($method, $datas = [])
{
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . API_KEY . "/" . $method;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datas);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    } else {
        return json_decode($res);
    }
}

$msg_id = bot('ForwardMessage', [    
'chat_id' => $channel,    
'from_chat_id' => $chat_id,    
'message_id' => $message_id    
])->result->message_id;
```

but i need php code that can chek channel if new post send from other admins, robot find post id and forward post to other channel that I have already specified in two channels that robot is admin

i read api bot of telegram there says about how can get post channel in this link: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update

in my bot i use setwebhook, which one of $channel_post or $chid is correct?

```
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$channel_post = $update->message->channel_post;
$chid = $update->channel_post->message->message_id;
```

Comment: You should add more code. And please edit your question - it is hard to understand.

Comment: my question is clear but i add more code and edited title of topic, if have question say to me and i try explain more details about it

Comment: There are typos, your title is too long, the code formatting is bad and there are no comments. So please - you wan't to have an answer - edit your question.

Comment: edited again, i think not typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow this code :

```
if( isset($update->channel_post) && $update->channel_post )
{

  if(isset($update->channel_post->text) && $update->channel_post->text)
  {
      $apiToken = "my_bot_api_token";

      $data = [
          'chat_id' => '@targetChannel',
          'text' => $update->channel_post->text
      ];





file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data) );
}


}
```